# Random Alert in Selenium Driver, how do I handle it?

Tags: java, selenium, testing, popup, alert

I am attempting to test www.uhc.com website using Selenium with Java and Chrome browser. The website has a pop-up that appears randomly at any point while the script is running, it is asking to take a survey with simple yes or no buttons. If I try to guess when this will happen then Selenium is waiting for the alert and the test fails. How can I pass the tests and dismiss the pop-ups that appears randomly?

Comment: Look into the webdriver event listener:  https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/events/WebDriverEventListener.html Run checks after any event that may trigger pop-up, test for existence of popup... if it exists run function for passing test.

Answer (score 0):

Always try to select the element and close it and catch the not found exception if selenium can't find it on the dom. If it can, close the popup by clicking the yes/no/close button. You'll find try/catch very useful with selenium